# What is the meaning of "...が出ない " in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, expressions

Context: there are two professor that are talking to each other; one is a long career professor while the other is a novice professor. This one lack of dignity,    seriousness.

The long career professor say to the novice professor:

> "私は」いつまでたっても教師の貫禄が出ないあなたに戸惑っています。"

Now, in this sentence I can not figure out the meaning of "貫禄が出ない". Maybe it is similar to "貫禄がない"?

May be the translation something like "Is your incorrigible lack of dignity as teacher that leave me perplexed (about you)."?

EDIT: Or "No matter how much time passes, (your) dignity as teacher will not come out, so I have perplexities about you/your request" (note: see the comment below).

Thk U in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting "incorrigible lack of dignity", particularly the "incorrigible" part.  Though a larger context might be useful.  The expectation of the speaker seem to be that あなた would definitely have a presence as a teacher; it's the lack of the presence (or dignity?) that is perplexing.  I don't know.  More context could help.

Comment: incorrigible is a my render for いつまでたっても. The vocabularies report  "no matter how much time passes​", "never", "for a long time", but any of this terms fit with the context. So I thought that an "incorregibile lack" as may be a lack of dignity can express the idea of something  that last in time, "no matter how much passes".

Comment: About more context, I dunno if can be useful, but here the previous sentence, said by the novice professor:
魔法の家系ではない日本人が初めてルーナノヴァ (it's a name of a school)に入ってきて、戸惑うことばかりでしょうし. 

They are talking about a new student, and the novice one is worried about the fact that this girl could have perplexities/ feel lost in the new context of the school, so she want help her becoming her tutor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

出る ("come/go out") comes with many different (but closely-related) shades of meaning (as does its English counterpart), and I think "develop" nicely captures the sense of the word as used here.

貫禄 is something like a "dignified air" about a person. It's generally a good thing to have, if having authority and commanding respect matter anything to you, but often it's something that only comes with experience. (Excepting the rare cases of naturals. They somehow exude the look and feel of many years of experience and accomplishment from the very start. Damn those naturals.)

So anyway, 貫禄が出ない means "a dignified air does not develop" (or "someone does not develop a dignified air"). 貫禄がない means "there is no dignified air (about a person)" (or "someone have no dignified air about them"). They mean similar things, yes. The speaker probably could have used 貫禄がない instead of 貫禄が出ない with their point remaining intact.

With a bit of trimming and smoothing, the quote goes like this:

> I'm quite baffled that you, after all this time, still haven't shown any sign of developing that dignified presence and air of a teaching professional.